# can not install moadmin in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mongodb

I am trying to use phpMoAdmin to use the gui in mongo database. I download the moadmin.php file and place it in the /var/www folder. But when I try to access it using localhost/moadmin , it tries to download the moadmin.zip file. Any kind of help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

First, try to unzip the moadmin.zip file.
Check if you have installed apache and php for Ubuntu.
Install the php-mongodb extension.